# Cannot create virtual environment in windows terminal supported by ubuntu shell

Tags: python, windows, pip, virtualenv

I installed windows terminal with Ubuntu Shell recently. I used `virtualenv` to create virtual environment. As next, I actived the environment with `source venv/Script/activate` properly. Then, I checked with pip to whether show something or not. But `pip.exe freeze` showed something although it has shouldn't after activate it.

```sh
(C:\Users
evza\Desktop\Project5.0env) nevzat@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/nevza/Desktop/Project$ pip.exe freeze
appdirs==1.4.4
distlib==0.3.1
filelock==3.0.12
six==1.15.0
virtualenv==20.2.2
(C:\Users
evza\Desktop\Project5.0env) nevzat@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/nevza/Desktop/Project$
```

```
appdirs==1.4.4
distlib==0.3.1
filelock==3.0.12
six==1.15.0
virtualenv==20.2.2
```

```
(C:\Users
evza\Desktop\Project5.0env) nevzat@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/nevza/Desktop/Project$ pip.exe -V
pip 20.3.3 from c:\users\nevza\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
(C:\Users
evza\Desktop\Project5.0env) nevzat@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/nevza/Desktop/Project$
```

These are installed my main computer previously and not belonging to created virtual environment.

What is the problem ? Why can't I use venv's pip after activate it ?

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution with different way and it works fine.

I installed `git bash` and added to windows terminal. I thought that it will be more secure with not using sudo command in windows environment. pip command works fine with git bash as well.